# Adding a picture a predefined location with a placeholder into a existing pdf form.

Tags: c#, image-processing, pdf-generation, itext

Question Revised and clarified (Thanks to Bruno for point me in the right direction)-

This post was originally made under great sleep deprivation and after reading, I see how it could be confusing. I want to make sure that others have this solution in the future and not have to spend loads of time trying to figure it out.

Here is my question and there is an answer below that solves it. 
I have a pdf form and I need to add an image to a specific location where I have put a place holder. How can I do this?

Comment: Michael, you are doing something that is incredibly wrong and that goes against all common sense (it may even be in violation with PAdES-6). You are *abusing* a digital signature field to add a raster image of a signature without applying a digital signature. If anyone answers your question in its current state, that person might be an accomplice to your attempt to fool your customer. So please, clarify your question: why do you want to replace a digital signature field by an image that is not a digital signature?

Comment: I certainly was not trying to do something wrong. I am bit new to this and am so thankful you would steer me in the right direction. I think I greatly misunderstood this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660839/add-signature-image-on-pdf-without-digitally-signing-it-using-itextsharp .What I am trying to accomplish is to take a signature that is captured from my application by either Topaz signature pad, or (mobile) JSignature fields. Once signed digitally I am trying trying to store it in the hard copy form. If I read  your e-signature book, will it cover legality of that?

Comment: @MichaelHoward The PDF AcroForm signature fields are originally designed to be used for digital signatures based on X.509 certificates, PKIs, etc, not for images. From the viewpoint of the legal framework which meanwhile exists for those PKI based digital signatures, therefore, one might have problems with your approach. In my opinion, though, there is no problem as long everyone is aware that the PDFs with the signature images you replace the signature fields with have no more legal value than an image of a document into which someone pasted some signature image using Photoshop.

Comment: Gosh. That is interesting. There are a whole list of devices that capture digital signatures from a digital pad. Does that make the signature captured with them in essence worthless?

Answer (score 0):

Just for future people who may be looking for the answer on how to best add an image to a pre-defined specific location into a pre-existing .pdf form, here is the answer.

```cs
/* This codes works for those who have a pre-created pdf form with a button in the location and size you want your image. 
  I reccomend acrobat pro, thought it has a monthly cost. There are additional free PDF editors
  instantiate a new PdfStamper that will create a new file from my existing form. The Reader reads in your template and the stamper makes a copy
  FileToPath and FileFromPath are strings i created above that hold the path
  */
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(fileFromPath), File.Create(FileToPath)))
{
    //get my buttons positions current location and height btn1 is the name of my button that exists in the pdf already  
    AcroFields.FieldPosition fieldPosition = stamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions("btn1")[0];

    //create a new button utilze the field position to set it's location. FYI this is a rectangle. I reccomend you read about those
    //it will save you tons of time to understand them. 
    PushbuttonField imageField = new

    //btn1Replaced is what I named the new button that will overwrite the old place holder button 
    PushbuttonField(stamper.Writer, fieldPosition.position, "btn1Replaced");

    //Here I set they layout from my old button to my new one
    imageField.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;

    //grab the image you want in your pdf imgPath is a string I wrone above to grab the image
    iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("imgPath");

    //set your buttons image property to be your image you just grabbed
    imageField.Image = img;

    //always scale to the size of the button
    imageField.ScaleIcon = PushbuttonField.SCALE_ICON_ALWAYS;
    imageField.ProportionalIcon = false;

    //make sure your button is read only and then it will not act like a button, it will act like an image. 
    imageField.Options = BaseField.READ_ONLY;

    //Get rid of the old button 
    stamper.AcroFields.RemoveField("btn1");

    //add my button and make sure it is on the correct page
    stamper.AddAnnotation(imageField.Field, fieldPosition.page);
                               
    stamper.Close();
}
```